# Collect EXIF data of a directory

Tags: scripting, exif

Is there a way to extract EXIF information of all images within a directory (into an output file)? Preferably I also need GPS data but this is not essential.

I only ask, as I have a number of directories with a large number of image files within, so automating the EXIF extraction would be useful.

Comment: Do you need something more elaborate than for example `for file in *.jpg; do echo "=== ${file} ===" >> outputfile; exiv2 "${file}" >> outputfile; done`? Or `find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec exiv2 '{}' ';' > outputfile` (though that, as is, might not include the image file names; it should be easy to adapt, though)?

Comment: I'll give this a go, will modify it to include file names. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -r . > exif.txt
```

(remove the `-r` if you didn't intend to recurse into sub-directories).

Note that GPS data  usually **is** in EXIF tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jhead` to do this.

You can do a loop to parse each file, then grep the pattern you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Great idea, will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as `exiftool` there's also [`exiv2`](http://www.exiv2.org/). Works similarly from the command line.

```
$ exiv2 *.jpg > exifs.txt
```

It lacks a recursive switch so you'd need to use a find command to walk it through a directory tree of image files.